# $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}$ for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Show $m_2(f(A))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

**Question:** Suppose $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $m_1(A)=0$, where $m_1$ is the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure.  Now, consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}$ for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  Show $m_2(f(A))=0$, where $m_2$ is the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R^2}$.

**My Attempt:** Since $m_1(A)=0$, we can cover $A$ with intervals whose sums go to $0$.  That is, for $\epsilon>0$, there are intervals $I_j=(x_j,y_j)$ which cover $A$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty m_1(I_j)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty |y_j-x_j|\leq\epsilon$.  Now, since these intervals cover $A$, we have that $f(I_j)$ covers $f(A)$, and so we have $$m_2(f(A))\leq\sum_{j=1}^\infty m_2(f(I_j))=\sum_{j=1}^\infty|f(x_j)-f(y_j)|^2\leq\sum_{j=1}^\infty(\sqrt{|x_j-y_j|})^2\leq\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j-y_j|\leq\epsilon$$ hence, we get the result.

I was wondering if this looked good, or if I had any small errors.  In particular, my inequalities/equalities and the way I applied the coverings. I appreciate any feedback and help!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Why is it true that $m_2(f(I_j)) = |f(x_j)-f(y_j)|^2$ (or even $m_2(f(I_j)) \leq |f(x_j)-f(y_j)|^2$)?

Comment: @SangchulLee Since the $I_j$'s cover $A$, and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty m_1(I_j)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty |x_j-y_j|$, and so then the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure would just be the standard distance in $\mathbb{R^2}$, right?

Comment: $f(I_j)$ is the image of the interval $I_j$ under $f$, so you are measuring the area (i.e., Lebesgue measure) of this set and not the squared distance between $f(x_j)$ and $f(y_j)$. My question is, why is the area of the set $f(I_j)$ equal to (or at least bounded from above by) $|f(x_j)-f(y_j)|^2$?

Comment: because we are covering $f(I_j)$ by rectangles extending from $I_j=(x_j,y_j)$... so I suppose instead of equality, it should be $\leq$... Are we allowed to do that?

Comment: In the worst case, the condition does not exclude the possibility that $f(x_j)=f(y_j)$ holds for some $j$'s. So in general it is not a good idea to use just information of the values of $f$ at those two endpoints. But here is a trick: Let $z_j=\frac{1}{2}(x_j+y_j)$ and note that, for any $x\in I_j$, we have $|x-z_j|\leq\frac{1}{2}|x_j-y_j|$, and so, $$|f(x)-f(z_j)|\leq\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}|x_j-y_j|}.$$ Then $f(I_j)$ lies in the closed ball of radius $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}|x_j-y_j|}$ centered at $z_j$, and so, $m(f(I_j))\leq\frac{\pi}{2}|x_j-y_j|$.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't think about that.... that's a neat trick!  Thank you!